# Why doesn't this script output to a text file when run from cron?

Tags: cron

I have created a Shell Script as below

**Sample.sh**

```
  echo "Hi there"
```

I also added cron job in cron tab which is under /etc/crontab as below

```
* * * * * /home/Sample.sh > /home/Sample.txt
```

I have created the Sample.txt file in /home/ directory.

I have also checked the permission for read and write for both the file

When I execute the Sample.sh file it works fine.it writes in Sample.txt file

Now I don't understand why it is not writing in the Text file from the cron task i scheduled

I am using Ubuntu 10.04

Please Help me in fixing this issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the **system crontab** which has a slightly different format; specifically, the date-time fields must be followed by a `user` field which tells *cron* who to run the command that follows as.

So the syntax in this case should be something like:

```
* * * * * username /home/username/Sample.sh > /home/username/Sample.txt
```